# Populating an array from a large array, two elements at a time

Tags: c, arrays, nesc

I have an array of 10 random elements, generated like this:

```
             for ( j = 0;j<10;j++)
                {

                    file[j] = rand();

                    printf("Element[%d] = %d\n", j, file[j] );                  
                }
```

Then I generate a new array with 2 elements. The value of the array is taken from the array above, and placed into the array with 2 elements. Like in the code sample below:

```
         for(i = packet_count, j = 0; j < 2; ++j, ++i)
            {
                    packet[j] = file[i] ;
                    ++packet_count ;
                    printf("\npacket: %d", packet[j]);

            }
                printf("\nTransmit the packet: %d Bytes", sizeof(packet));
```

The output is shown below:

> ```
> Telosb mote Timer start.
> Element[0] = 36
> Element[1] = 141
> Element[2] = 66
> Element[3] = 83
> Element[4] = 144
> Element[5] = 137
> Element[6] = 142
> Element[7] = 175
> Element[8] = 188
> Element[9] = 69
>
> packet: 36
> packet: 141
> Transmit the packet: 2 Bytes
> ```

I want to run through the array and take the next two values and place them in the packet array and so on, until the last element in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run through the big array, and select the values to be copied in the little array, resseting `j` to zero when it is equal to 2:

```
j = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  packet[j] = file[i];
  printf("\npacket: %d", packet[j]);
  j++;
  if(j == 2) { 
    j = 0;
    printf("\nTransmit the packet: %d Bytes", sizeof(packet));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the modulus operator.  Example:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    packet[i % 2] = file[i] ;
    printf("\npacket: %d", packet[i % 2]);

    if(i % 2)
        printf("\nTransmit the packet: %d Bytes", sizeof(packet));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Already there have been many interesting solutions posted here.Yet i would like to add one more. You can use xor operator also.
`c=c^1` flips the value of c between 0 and 1.when `c=0,c^1=1` and when `c=1,c^1=0.`

```
int i,c=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
     packet[c] = file[i];         
     printf("\npacket: %d", packet[c]);
     if(c==1)
         printf("\nTransmit the packet: %d Bytes", sizeof(packet));
     c=c^1;
}
```

Hope it helps.Happy coding!!